# Android dataBinding - how to use bool resource to trigger visibility of layout

Tags: android, data-binding

I currently have a bool.xml file in android which looks like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<bool name="showAds">true</bool>
    </resources>
```

Now i have a layout.xml file which uses databinding.  I want to show or hide the visilibity of a adView based on a the boolean showAds defined above. So far i have this:

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="@{@bool/showAds ? View.Visible:View:gone}"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1234567/34343">
```

but it does not compile. how can i get the boolean to decide if the ad should show or not ?The syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Correct the syntax of condition View.Visible:View:gone

```
android:visibility="@{@bool/showAds ? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
```

and you need to import View in the data section:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Where can this `<data>` be tag found?

Comment: @wutzebaer You create the data tag nested under your <layout> tag. See the data binding set-up here; https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: hi the expression seems not to work even if i pass the gone value directly `android:visibility="@{0x00000008}"` the view is still not gone

Comment: can someone please help me with this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063963/android-databinding-textview-not-visible-depending-on-a-boolean-value

Answer (score 15):

If you don't like adding the View import (in each layout where needed), you can simply define a `@BindingConversion` annotated method:

```
@BindingConversion
public static int convertBooleanToVisibility(boolean visible) {
    return visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}
```

The annotated method can be in whatever Java file in your project.

Then you can simply use

```
android:visibility="@{@bool/showAds}"
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to make two of these?  

One that chooses between visible and gone.  

Another that chooses between visible and invisible.

Comment: Good question. I don't think it could work using the normal android:visibility since I wouldn't know how it could know which conversion to pick

Comment: When a BindingConversion or a BindingMethod seems a bit limited, use a BindingAdapter. You can generate your own attributes. For example: Use `android:visibility` with the BindingConversion for visible/gone and `android:invisible` as a BindingAdapter where you actually do the `view.setVisibility(theBoolean);`