# Android dataBinding - TextView not visible depending on a boolean value

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-databinding

I'm trying to make a `TextView` visible depending on when a `boolean`'s value is set to `true` and a `LinearLayout`'s visibility depending on the `false` value of the same `boolean` variable using `dataBinding`. The problem is that only `LinearLayout`'s visibility is set and not of the `TextView`'s although when I log the `boolean`'s value it's state is changing as per the control flow.

Below is my code any help is much appreciated as I'm stuck with this since last night and sorry if this is a noob question as I'm new to `dataBinding`. I'm setting the value twice in both `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` just to test the flow and log

**fragment layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
  <data>
    <variable
        name="isLoading"
        type="boolean"
        />
    <variable
        name="profileViewModel"
        type="com.example.siddhi.mvvm_login.viewmodel.ProfileViewModel"
        />
  </data>
  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logging_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/logging_in"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:visibleGone="@{isLoading}"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:visibleGone="@{!isLoading}"
        >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_width"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_height"
          android:src="@drawable/gfee_logo"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/emp_pk"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:contentDescription="Emp_pk"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp"
          android:text="@{profileViewModel.emp_pk}"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/emp_lic"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:contentDescription="Emp_lic"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp"
          android:text="@{profileViewModel.emp_lic}"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          />

    </LinearLayout>

  </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

**CustomBindingAdapter**

```
public class CustomBindingAdapter {
  @BindingAdapter("visibleGone") public static void showHide(View view, boolean show) {
    view.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    Log.e("show", "" + show);
  }
}
```

**Java Fragment**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
  private ProfilefragmentBinding binding;

  public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.profilefragment, container, false);
    Log.e("FirstTimeIsLoading","" + binding.getIsLoading());
    binding.setIsLoading(true);
    Log.e("SecondTimeIsLoading","" + binding.getIsLoading());
    return binding.getRoot();
  }

  @Override public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final ProfileViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
    binding.setProfileViewModel(viewModel);
    Log.e("ThirdTimeIsLoading","" + binding.getIsLoading());
    binding.setIsLoading(true);
    Log.e("FourthTimeIsLoading","" + binding.getIsLoading());
    observeViewModel(viewModel);
  }

  private void observeViewModel(final ProfileViewModel viewModel) {
    viewModel.getObservableProfile().observe(this, new Observer<List<UserInfo>>() {
      @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable List<UserInfo> userInfos) {
        if (userInfos != null) {
          binding.setIsLoading(false);
          Log.e("isloadingFalse","" + binding.getIsLoading());
          viewModel.setEmp_pk(userInfos.get(0).getEmpPk());
          viewModel.setEmp_lic(userInfos.get(0).getEmpLicenceType());
        } else {
          Log.e("userInfos is null", "");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**My logcat of the boolean value**

```
E/FirstTimeIsLoading: false
E/SecondTimeIsLoading: true
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15486(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 11.385ms total 63.940ms
E/ThirdTimeIsLoading: true
E/FourthTimeIsLoading: true

                       [ 03-02 01:18:22.091  5874: 5874 D/         ]
                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd98cd400, tid 5874


                       [ 03-02 01:18:22.110  5874: 5874 W/         ]
                       Process pipe failed
E/show: true
E/show: false
E/isloadingFalse: false
E/setEmp_pk: 166
E/show: false
E/show: true
```

**logcat after** adding `Log.e("show", "" + show + " " + view.getClass().getName());` to `CustomBindingAdapter`

```
03/02 14:08:07: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk D:\Siddhi\Local Projects\MVVM_Login\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.siddhi.mvvm_login/com.example.siddhi.mvvm_login.view.ui.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 3170 on device genymotion-google_pixel_xl___7_1_0___api_25___1440x2560-192.168.87.101:5555
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.siddhi.mvvm_login-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
E/FirstTimeIsLoading: false
E/SecondTimeIsLoading: true
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
E/ThirdTimeIsLoading: true
E/FourthTimeIsLoading: true

                       [ 03-02 03:45:18.242  3170: 3170 D/         ]
                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd6e2d140, tid 3170


                       [ 03-02 03:45:18.250  3170: 3170 W/         ]
                       Process pipe failed
E/show: true android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
E/show: false android.widget.LinearLayout
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

          [ 03-02 03:45:18.361  3170: 3194 D/         ]
          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd6e2d5c0, tid 3194
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
E/EGL_emulation: tid 3194: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xd6bea500, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
E/response_data: com.example.siddhi.mvvm_login.service.model.LoginResponse@649f367
E/isloadingFalse: false
E/setEmp_pk: 166
E/show: false android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
E/show: true android.widget.LinearLayout
```

**Debugger screenshot**
[image]

**LoginRepo code where I'd made a mistake of setting the thread delay to 200 rather than 2000**

```
    public LiveData<List<UserInfo>> getUserLiveData(String id, String password, String device_id, String token) {
    final MutableLiveData<List<UserInfo>> user = new MutableLiveData<>();
    final MutableLiveData<String> emp_pk = new MutableLiveData<>();

    gfeeLoginService.getProfileDetails(id, password,"","").enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
      @Override public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
        simulateDelay();
        Log.e("response_data","" + response.body());
        user.setValue(response.body().getUserInfo());
        emp_pk.setValue(response.body().getUserInfo().get(0).getEmpPk());
      }

      @Override public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        user.setValue(null);
        Log.e("Data", "is NULL! " + t);
      }
    });
    return user;
  }

  private void simulateDelay() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(2000); //mistake of adding 200 rather than 2000
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: it gave me the following result:

class 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView'

class 'android.widget.LinearLayout'

Comment: yes that is my logcat output

Comment: because I've used Log.e to log not Log.d, a dirty habit I need to get rid off as D if for debugging and E for error

Comment: @pskink could you please suggest any solution for it?

Comment: how if you dont want to post your logcat after adding stuff i suggested? simply try: `Log.e("show", "" + show + " " + view.getClass().getName());` and post the whole logcat output

Comment: Sorry I commented the output after what you suggested. I'll post the logcat one moment please

Comment: @pskink Please check

Comment: is it after calling `Log.e("show", "" + show + " " + view.getClass().getName());` ?

Comment: yes after adding what you suggested, I've added Log.d to differentiate the new log from previous one. D/show2: class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView 

D/show2: class android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: no, it is not - i dont see any: `<boolean> <fullClassName>` in the output - just call what i wrote

Comment: @pskink Sorry I missed out on show variable in the log, I apologize please check now

Comment: so you have first: `true android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` and then `false android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` - it means that `logging_in` TextView should be GONE but you say its VISIBLE? if so there must be some other code to call it to VISIBLE, check your code

Comment: to be sure setup a breakpoint in `View#setVisibility` method and check when it is called

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake I had set a thread with a delay of 200 rather than 2000 milliseconds before the transition happened between TextView and LinearLayout that's why TextView was not appearing

Answer (score 1):

You can make observable boolean  in model class and set true and false as your requirement.

e.g

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/logging_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/logging_in"
        android:visibility="@{profileViewModel.isLoading ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"/>
```